# How to use IF THEN in SQL, specific scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

My current issue is with trying to build a query that given a conditions it gives me a specific count.

I need to pull a list of users who have had items selling on our site but currently have no items listed. The result should be a list of users who ONLY have items that are not currently published.

My query is as follows:

```
select `products`.`id` as 'product id', `users`.`id` as 'user id', 
`users`.`full_name` as 'user full name',`users`.`email` as 'user email'
(CASE WHEN `products`.`is_published` = 1
    THEN count(`products`.`ìs_published`) = 0
    ELSE END )
from `users`,`products`
and `users`.`is_active` = 1
and `products`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
group by `users`.`id`
order by 'user id' asc;
```

For context, if products.is_published = 1 it means that user has a live item, if it's = 0, it means the item is not published and thus the seller is inactive. However, there are cases in which a seller may have items that were sold in the past, plus live items so they would also show up even if products.is_published = 0, because they've had both.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I clarified my questions a bit more, let me know if that helps. @GordonLinoff

Comment: Seems like your `WHERE` is missing here.  Why isn't your current query working?  We don't have access to your data and can't tell, hence the reason we need sample data and desired results.  Check into using the "new" `JOIN` [syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can count items for users in subquery, like this:

```
select users.id as 'user id'
, users.full_name as 'user full name'
, users.email as 'user email'
, (select count(1) from products where is_published = 1 and user_id = users.id) as 'count of published'
from users
Where is_active = 1
order by 'user id' asc;
```

if you need count only when user have published products try this:

```
select users.id as 'user id'
, users.full_name as 'user full name'
, users.email as 'user email'
, pc.c as 'count of published'
from users
inner join (select user_id, count(1) as c from products where is_published = 1 group by user_id) as pc on pc.user_id = users.id
Where is_active = 1
order by 'user id' asc;
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! That worked, now the only other thing for me would be to filter out where 'count of published' is more than 0. That'll give me the correct number of inactive users.

Comment: if you need list of inactive users, select * from users where not exists (select 1 from products where is_published = 1 and user_id = users.id)...